# PHP: Notice: Undefined index where the session variable is defined

Tags: php, debugging, session-variables

I am making a registration system with an e-mail verifier. Your typical "use this code to verify" type of thing.

I want a session variable to be stored, so that when people complete their account registration on the registration page and somehow navigate back to the page on accident, it reminds them that they need to activate their account before use.

What makes this problem so hard to diagnose is that I have used many other session variables in similar ways, but this one is not working at all. Here's my approach:

```
/* This is placed after the mail script and account creation within the same if 
statement. Things get executed after it, so I know it's placed correctly. */

$_SESSION['registrationComplete'] = TRUE; 

// I've tried integer 1 and 'Yes' as alternatives.
```

Now to check for the variable, I placed this at the top of the page.

```
echo $_SESSION['registrationComplete']; // To see if it's setting. This gives the
                                        // undefined index notice.

if (isset($_SESSION['registrationComplete'])) {

// Alternatively, I have nested another if that simply tests if it's TRUE.

    echo $_SESSION['registrationComplete']; // When echo'd here, it displays nothing.

    echo '<p>Congratulations, Foo! Go to *link to Bar*.</p>';

}
```

Now, I used to have the page redirect to a new page, but I took that out to test it. When the page reloads from submit, my message in the if statement above appears and then I get an `Notice: Undefined index: registrationComplete blah blah` from the echoing of the session var!

Then if I ever go back to the page, it ignores the if statement all together.

I have tested for typos and everything, clearing session variables in case old ones from testing were interfering, but I am having no luck. A lot of Googling just shows people suppressing these errors, but that sounds insane! Not only that, but I am not getting the same persistence of session variables elsewhere on my site. Can someone point out if I'm doing something blatantly wrong? Help! Thanks!

FYI, I read several related questions and I am also a beginner, so I may not know how to utilize certain advice without explanation.

**As requested, more code, heavily annotated to keep it brief**

```
var_dump($_SESSION);

// It's here to analyze that index message. I guess it's not important.
echo $_SESSION['registrationComplete']; 

if (isset($_SESSION['registrationComplete'])) { 

    // The golden ticket! This is what I want to appear so badly.
    echo 'Congratulations, Foo! Go to *link to Bar*.';

}


// Explanation: I don't want logged in users registering. 
// The else statement basically executes the main chunk of code.

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    echo 'You are logged in as someone already.';

}

else {

    if (isset($_POST['submitRegister'])) {

        // Code: Database connection and parsing variables from the form.

        if (!empty($email) && !empty($email2) && $email == $email2 && !empty($displayName) && !empty($password) && !empty($password2) && $password == $password2) {

            // Code: Query to retrieve data for comparison.

            if (mysqli_num_rows($registrationData) == 0) {

                // Code: Generates the salt and verification code.

                // Code: Password hashing and sending data to verify database.

                // E-mail the verification code.

                $_SESSION['registrationComplete'] = 'yes';

            }

            else {

                // Some error handling is here.
                $registerError = 'The e-mail address you entered is already in use.';

            }

        }

        // the elseif, elseif, and else are more error handling.

        elseif ($email != $email2) { $registerError = 'Your e-mails did not match'; }

        elseif ($password != $password2) { $registerError = 'Passwords didn\'t match.'; }

        else { $registerError = 'Filled out completely?'; }

        // If the registration was submitted, but had errors, this will print the form again.

        if (!isset($_SESSION['registrationComplete'])) { require_once REF_DIR . REF_REGISTERFORM; }


        // IMPORTANT! it turns out my code did not work, I forgot I had the same statement elsewhere.
        else { echo 'Congratulations, Foo! Go to *link to Bar*.'; }
    }

    // Creates form.

    else { require_once REF_DIR . REF_REGISTERFORM; }

}
```

Comment: Are you making sure that session_start is called at the top of the page to continue the session? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: How much data are you storing in session variables?

Comment: @Jack: Yes. I large chunk of the site that contains session_start() is appended to the content via require_once. If something went wrong, I would also be missing half my site, so I think it may be safe to rule it out.

Comment: @George: Do you mean in general or just the one I'm having trouble with? The one I am having trouble with, I have tried several things. I have tried TRUE, 1, and 'Y'. I just need some boolean type data to be saved.

Comment: I'm wondering about the total size of the session.

Comment: @George: This is really the only other session variable outside of the login script. The login script saves three session variables, all very short and just contain data about the member.

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($_SESSION)`?  Wrap that output with `<pre></pre>` for better formatting.

Comment: @George: Very awesome function! The output was `array(0) { }`. Ironically, my `if (isset($_SESSION['registrationComplete']))` output appeared. However, this only happens after submit/$_POST. If I return to the page through a link, it's gone.

Comment: Sounds like your doing some conditional processing.  I think you need to provide more code.

Comment: I edited the main post. I took out a lot of code and replaced it with comments. It's mostly just parsing and such that is unrelated to the issue. I provided all the conditionals except for the code for salt creation.

Comment: Ok, where's your call to `session_start()`?  I don't see it anywhere in here.

Comment: @George: I have a `require once` at the top that I did not include (did not want to make it even longer). In the top part that is appended, the `session_start()` is right at the top.

Comment: @Tarik And it's not in a conditional or something like that?

Comment: @George: No, I keep it there so every page has a `session_start()`.

Comment: Ok, step through the flow. Initially, the session variables are not set and the form is displayed. The user submits the form and the form is processed. If the required info is supplied correctly, session variables are set and a link is provided to continue. Otherwise, the form is presented again.  So, the problem occurs when the user clicks on the link and then backs up?

Comment: George, you indirectly led me right to my issue. I had some code to clear sessions in the file I used `require once` on. I hid it in an HTML comment, but I forgot how PHP is executed. Even though my editor highlighted it as an HTML comment, it was still getting executed. I almost feel as if this whole question doesn't really serve a purpose. I wish I could somehow provide reputation to you for working with me.

Comment: @Tarik I posted an answer with the basics of debugging/troubleshooting, which is ultimately what I was posting in comments here.  As to the value of the question, I say leave it be.  It's a good illustration of debugging and some basic issues of session handling.  I would add a comment to my answer noting the ultimate issue and/or update the question with a note about the issue.  That should make it reasonably useful for a future reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came down to the basics of debugging/troubleshooting.

1. Understand as much as you can about the technique/library/function/whatever that you're trying to use.
2. Inspect the salient bits and make sure that they are what you expect or what they should be. (There's a slight difference between those two, depending on the situation.)
3. If that doesn't bring you towards a solution, step back and make sure you're understanding the situation.  This may mean simplifying things so that you're only dealing with the issue at hand, i.e. create a separate, simpler test case which exposes the same problem.  Or, it may simply mean that you stop coding and work through the flow of your code to make sure it is really doing what you think it is doing.

A typical issue with sessions not working is forgetting to use `session_start()` (near or at the top) of any page which uses sessions.

One of my favorite snippets of PHP code, for debugging:

```
print '<pre>';
var_dump($some_variable);
print '</pre>';
```

I try to use `print` for debugging and `echo` for regular output.  It makes it easier to spot debugging code, once it's goes beyond a few trivial bits of output.

Meanwhile, `var_dump` will print a bit more info about the variable, like it's type and size.  It's important to wrap it in `<pre></pre>` so that it's easier to read the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['registrationComplete'])) {
```

Comment: No luck, but thanks for trying. It gets me the exact same result as isset. So, I can conclude it's getting set as something, I just don't know why it loses it's persistence. And if it's getting set before the variable is referenced, why would I get an Undefined Index error? Hmm.

Comment: @Tarik can you confirm 100% that it's the correct line and file in the error message?

Comment: Yes. The undefined index notice appears wherever I try to echo $_SESSION['registrationComplete'] with the exception of the isset if statement. I can't seem to figure out why it is not setting or staying set?

Comment: @Tarik you are starting a session using `session_start()`, right?

Comment: Yes. I large chunk of the site that contains session_start() is appended to the content via require_once. If something went wrong, I would also be missing half my site, so I think it may be safe to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the warning after the message is printed, this cannot come from the variable echoing because according to your code it would be thrown before printing that message. Are you sure you don't use $_SESSION['registrationComplete'] beyond the if statement? Try to add exit or die() before the closing bracket of the if and see if the notice disappears.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I get the error if I reference it before the if (isset['registrationComplete']). I took it out so I could see if the variable had any value. When I place the echo inside the previously mentioned if statement, the error message does not appear, but the problem of it's persistence still remains.