# PHP Notice: Undefined index Error with Session

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Notice: Undefined index where the session variable is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346822/php-notice-undefined-index-where-the-session-variable-is-defined)
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Ok, so this is the Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: overview_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\home.php on line 6

And this is my code:

```
 <?php session_start();

   $sess = $_SESSION["overview_id"];

   if(isset($sess)){
     header("Location: account.php");
   }

 ?>
```

Any help would be cool.

Thank you.

Comment: $_SESSION["overview_id"] is not defined. just like the error message said

Comment: This isn't an error, its a *Notice*, it's just informing you of some nice-to-dos

Comment: I don't get it: if you check whether that `overview_id` element is defined (and you DO check it, with `isset`), why do you create a temporary variable, assign this value to it and only then check this variable? Why don't just `if(isset($_SESSION['overview_id']))` then? I mean, what's the reasoning behind this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your third line to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['overview_id'])){
```

Instead and remove the second line.

Answer (score 0):

you set up session_id before checking, so it always must have at least default value assigned before You set up it to another variable, so better use this

```
if(isset($_SESSION["overview_id"])){
    header("Location: account.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the code that you have presented:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["overview_id"])){
    header("Location: account.php");
}

?>
```

This would resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

since `$_SESSION["overview_id"]` is not set, then `$sess = $_SESSION["overview_id"];` will fail. This is how you have to do your test:

```
<?php session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION["overview_id"])) {
        header("Location: account.php");
    }
?>
```